# pandas iterate over specific item in columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I loaded a csv file with different aspects of a company such as name, valuation, location and investors and looped over the investors-column.

```
df = pd.read_csv("Unicorntable_india.csv")

for column in df.columns[-1:]:
    print(df[column])
```

In the column `investors` are multiple investors per loop-item such as investors: KPCB, Ventures, SoftBank, so my questions is how I can loop over those items?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
investors = df['investors]

for inv in investors:
   print(inv)
```

Maybe could be useful:

```
df['investors].value_counts()
```